# What are the default namespaces for django authentication URLs?

Tags: python, django, namespaces, django-urls, django-authentication

I changed my app's `urls.py` to have a namespace `app_name = 'somename'`. And then did these,

1. Changed `reverse('url-name')` to `reverse('somename:url-name')`.
2. Changed `{% url 'url-name' %}` to `{% url 'somename:url-name' %}`.
3. Changed a `{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == "url-name" %}` to `{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == "somename:url-name" %}`.

For `accounts` app, I only have two custom views for `login` and `signup`. So a `reverse` like `reverse('accounts:login')` is working but `reverse('accounts:password_reset')` (part of default django auth) is not working.

**Here is what I tried,**

1. Replaced `reverse('accounts:password_reset')` with `reverse('auth:password_reset')`.
2. Replaced `reverse('accounts:password_reset')` with `reverse('password_reset')`.

Solution 1 did not work. Solution 2 is working. I also tried changing `path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))` in my project's `urls.py` to `path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth'))` and `path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls, namespace='accounts'))`. Neither worked.

**project/urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('books/', include('library.urls'))
]
```

**accounts/urls.py**

```py
app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.CustomSignup.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.CustomLogin.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

Why namespacing `password_reset` with `accounts` and `auth` fail? Is there a documentation page that has default namespaces that can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell by reading the source code they are not namespaced at all, you can normally only refer to them by name as you are now.

If you want to have them namespaced, you could include them into your `accounts`' `urlpatterns`, rather than your project's and add the namespace manually:

```py
app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.CustomSignup.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.CustomLogin.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='accounts')),
]
```